# java calendar add is not working

Tags: java, date, calendar, addition

I used add method to add 3 days to calendar.

but I found that It is not working correctly.

```
Calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 7);
```

please let me know what is wrong.

```
while(dateIdx < nowDate)
{
    int tmpYear = startCal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int tmpMonth = startCal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
    int tmpDay = startCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

    System.out.println(+tmpYear+tmpMonth+tmpDay+ "- "+tmpYear+tmpMonth+(tmpDay+6));
    startCal.add(Calendar.DATE, 7); //used add method here
    tmpYear = startCal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    tmpMonth = startCal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
    tmpDay = startCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    dateIdx = tmpYear*10000 + tmpMonth*100 +tmpDay; //it is not incorrect result
}
```

Comment: you have added 7 days.

Comment: What is the input? What output did you get? What did you expect it to be?

Comment: FRIDAY + 7 still equals FRIDAY

Comment: what is the type of `nowDate`?

Comment: The only thing I want is just add 7 days to calendar object's Date data. The problem is the add method is not working... not at all. Please ignore other things.

Comment: if that is your question you have done it correctly by using `startCal.add(Calendar.DATE, 7)`

Comment: *but I found that It is not working correctly* - but how did you find?

Comment: Because I used Debugging tool to check it is working correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The process is working just fine...

```
Calendar startCal = Calendar.getInstance();
int tmpYear = startCal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int tmpMonth = startCal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
int tmpDay = startCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

System.out.println(tmpYear + "/" + tmpMonth + "/" + tmpDay);
System.out.println(startCal.getTime());
startCal.add(Calendar.DATE, 7); //used add method here
tmpYear = startCal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
tmpMonth = startCal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
tmpDay = startCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

System.out.println(tmpYear + "/" + tmpMonth + "/" + tmpDay);
System.out.println(startCal.getTime());
```

Which outputs...

```
2015/5/4
Wed May 20 22:07:14 EST 2015
2015/5/4
Wed May 27 22:07:14 EST 2015
```

`DAY_OF_WEEK` indicates the "day" it is (Monday through Sunday), so adding 7 to any date will give you the same `DAY_OF_WEEK.

Perhaps you meant to use `DATE` instead

```
tmpDay = startCal.get(Calendar.DATE);
```

As a side note, I would encourage you to make use Java 8's new Time API or Joda-Time over `Calendar`, you'll generally find it simpler, but that's me

Comment: Yes. As he said, "Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK"  was wrong.  It was the problem..... Thank you for your help. And have a nice day Blip